# Bubble Sort in C with zero

Tags: c, bubble-sort

So, I'm trying bubble sort for the first time in C and my code works except for the fact that if I enter 0 as an input the sorting makes everything else 0. I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. Thank you.

```
/* Double-Click To Select Code */


#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
 int w,f,temp,j;
 float arr[25];

 printf("Enter the number of elements in the Array: ");
 scanf("%d",&f);
 printf("\nEnter the elements:\n\n");

 for(w=0 ; w<f ; w++)
 {
  printf(" Array[%d] = ",w);
  scanf("%f",&arr[w]);
 }


for(w=0 ; w<f ; w++)
{
    for(j=0 ; j<f-w-1 ; j++)
    {
    if(arr[j]>arr[j+1]) //Swapping Condition is Checked
        {
        temp=arr[j];
        arr[j]=arr[j+1];
        arr[j+1]=temp;
        }
    }
}
printf("\nThe Sorted Array is:\n\n");
for(w=0 ; w<f ; w++)
    {
    printf(" %4f",arr[w]);
    }
}
```

if I input say,
1.000
0.333
0

the output would be: 0.000  0.000 1.000

Comment: `temp` should be a `float`, not an `int`.

Comment: Sorting is good, there is no problem when i enter 0 as an input?

Comment: temp should be float and when you are using 25 as max number of input int arr, then enforce user also to not enter more than 25, else you will corrupt the stack.

Comment: there is no problem sorting is good. void main() is obsolete plz use int main() and return 0. use float temp instead of int temp

Comment: I've changed the temp into float and it worked. Thank you very much

Comment: change temp as float

Answer (score 1):

I tested. Just change the type of temp to float. This is working;

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
     int w,f,j;
     float arr[25],temp;

     printf("Enter the number of elements in the Array: ");
     scanf("%d",&f);
     printf("\nEnter the elements:\n\n");

     for(w=0 ; w<f ; w++)
     {
      printf(" Array[%d] = ",w);
      scanf("%f",&arr[w]);
     }


    for(w=0 ; w<f ; w++)
    {
        for(j=0 ; j<f-w-1 ; j++)
        {
        if(arr[j]>arr[j+1]) //Swapping Condition is Checked
            {
            temp=arr[j];
            arr[j]=arr[j+1];
            arr[j+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nThe Sorted Array is:\n\n");
    for(w=0 ; w<f ; w++)
        {
        printf(" %4f",arr[w]);
        }
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to sort floats, you need temp to be a float:

```
int w,f,j;
float arr[25];
float temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

the temp variable being of int type truncates the float value. change it to float.In your output 0.000 0.000 1.000 the first or the second zero was 0.33 
truncated to zero and the third value is at is